# How do I input a text file directly into Java?

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I heard something like this

```
java myMainClass < myInputFile.txt
```

will provide a file as input to my Java program.

But how do I access that input?

Comment: I thought `java myMainClass yourFile` would work better

Answer (score 2):

That command is piping the file into STDIN, which in Java you can access as `System.in`.

For example, if you want to use a Scanner:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```